# Iterating primes using mpz_nextprime

Tags: c++, gmp

In C++, I want to print the first `n` prime numbers (for this example let's assume `n=1000`).

In order to do this, I've found [`mpz_nextprime`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Number-Theoretic-Functions.html) from the GMP library.

I'd assume you use it like this

```
int n = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    n = mpz_nextprime(n);
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

but this doesnt compile as `mpz_nextprime` takes two `mpz_t` arguments.

How can you use `mpz_nextprime` in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for `mpz_nextprime` using `mpz_t` instead of normal integer types like `int` or `long` is that after a certain point the prime numbers will be too large to be representable in a `int` or `long`.

Here's a snippet of code to print all up to the 1000th prime number:

```
#include <gmp.h>

int main() {
    mpz_t n;
    mpz_init(n);
    mpz_set_ui(n, 2);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { // first 1000 primes
        mpz_nextprime(n, n);
        cout << "The " << (i + 1) << "th " << " prime is " << mpz_get_ui(n) << endl;
    }
}
```

Note that this code will only work up to a certain prime number because in order to print it, we convert it to an unsigned int using `mpz_get_ui` here.

If you want to print larger prime numbers, use `mpz_get_str` (but don't forget to `free()` the string if you use `NULL` as first parameter).